# Parallel Trend and DID Estimation

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

I am trying to estimate the effect of climate shock on hours spent in paid labor by women. The key independent variables are time dummy (that takes 1 if shock happened, 0 otherwise; there are two pre-shock periods and one post-shock period), treatment (that takes 1 if the district where an individual woman is living is affected by the shock), and the DID coefficient which is interaction between time dummy and treatment.

While I am getting nice statistically significant DID coefficient, my parallel trend assumption is not satisfied when I run regression using one of the pre-event period as time dummy=1 and 0 for the other pre-event.
Can someone explain what is going wrong in my way of testing parallel trend assumption? I am using stata for the analysis.